# Python Code Trouble for Counting Letters in a Sentence

Tags: python

I need to write a code that counts how many times a letter appears in a sentence and I can not seem to figure out what I did wrong.

```
def count_occurences(sent, letter):
    countletter = 0
    for char in sent:
        if char == "letter":
            countletter = count + 1
    return countletter
```

Comment: You did not indicate what is wrong, so we cannot really help you;

Comment: Why not use the designated `str` method instead? `sent.count(letter)`.

Answer (score 3):

Did you mean to do this ?

```
def count_occurences(sent, letter):
    countletter = 0
    for char in sent:
        if char == letter:
            countletter = countletter + 1
    return countletter
```

Notice in the if statement, the absence of quotes.

`letter` references the variable, `"letter"` is a string containing the 6 characters l, e, t, t, e and r.

Additionnaly, as mentionned by Arifa Chan in the comments, your counting method is incorrect.

You used to:

```
countletter = count + 1
```

Where count is undefined. Instead, use:

```
countletter = countletter + 1
```

---

However, while this answer fixes your current code, as pointed out in the comments, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76999943/6213883) other answer is more efficient.

Comment: How about *return sent.count(letter)* ?

Comment: @DarkKnight That is indeed another solution. But it has already been provided as an answer by Ξένη-Γήινος.

Comment: `countletter += 1`

Comment: Please, if you have another solution, just write your own answer, instead of listing all possibilities as comments...

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are right in fixing your code, but your method is inefficient.

To find count of `char` in `string`,
a more efficient (but still inefficient way) would be `sum(1 for c in string if c == char)`.

The most efficient way would be using the `count` method of `str` class, which does exactly what you want: `string.count(char)`.

---

I thoroughly profiled  the code, I generated a random string with 4096 characters, and my original `sum` method is indeed slower. I have fixed it to `sum(1 for i in text if i == char)`, which is much faster than the fixed version of  original poster's method.

The profiling information is below:

```py
In [196]: import random

In [197]: from string import printable

In [198]: text = ''.join(random.choices(printable, k=4096))

In [199]: %timeit text.count('e')
2.61 µs ± 89 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [200]: %timeit sum(i == 'e' for i in text)
455 µs ± 7.15 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

In [201]: %%timeit
     ...: s = 0
     ...: for i in text:
     ...:     s += i == 'e'
284 µs ± 56.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

In [202]: %%timeit
     ...: s = 0
     ...: for i in text:
     ...:     if i == 'e':
     ...:         s += 1
172 µs ± 1.44 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

In [203]: %timeit sum(1 for i in text if i == 'e')
157 µs ± 1.06 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

`text.count('e')` is the fastest, and nothing can compare with its efficiency, `str` methods are implemented in C...

The reason the original method is slower is because it performs assignment each iteration, the count variable is mutated each iteration, even if the condition is `False` and there would be no change. By using `if` to checking the condition and only increment when `True`, there would be much fewer increment operations and no unnecessary operations, so the code is much faster.

Comment: While it is true that `str.count` is faster, your `sum` approach is about 80% slower than OP's

Answer (score 0):

```
if char == "letter":
```

This line here is not ok. It should be: `if char == letter`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_occurences(sent, letter):
    countletter = 0
    for char in sent:
        if char == letter:
            countletter = count + 1
    return countletter
```

you were using `letter` string instead of your passed variable

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion might be to have a dictionary with the letters occurrences

```py
def count_occurences(sent):
    occurences_d = {}
    for i in sent:
        if i in occurences_d:
            occurences_d[i]+=1
        else:
            occurences_d[i]=1
    return occurences_d
```

Usage involves also case sensitive:

```
t = 'Test sentence'
count_occurences(t)
{'T': 1, 'e': 4, 's': 2, 't': 2, ' ': 1, 'n': 2, 'c': 1}
```

Comment: That's essentially what the *collections.Counter* class does. Functional but slow